# ¿Por qué al tocar el botón más de una vez se crean más botones en lugar de recargarse la página?

Tags: javascript, html

Encontré un código en esta misma página y lo empecé a modificar, y lo que ocurrió fue que no obtuve el resultado que quería.

El resultado que tuve: al tocar el botón se creaba otro botón y cada vez que tocaba el botón hacía lo mismo, creaba muchos botones sin eliminar los otros, o más bien no se ejecutaba el `else` de la función.

El resultado que quería: al tocar el botón dos veces seguidas la página se recargue, en cambio el código creaba más y más botones.

La pregunta en concreto es ¿por qué ocurre esto y no lo que yo quería?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>javaScriptEjemplo</title>
     <script>
     
function activar(){

    var num=0;

    if(num<=0){
  document.body.innerHTML += "<div><button id='b1'>Nuevo Botón</button></div>";
  num=1;
  }
else{
    reload();
    }
}
      </script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="activar()" value="menu">Activar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu variable num es una variable local de tu funcion y cada vez que des click y llames a la funcion se pondrá como 0 y nunca entrará a tu else.

Lo que tienes que hacer es que tu variable num, declararla como variable global.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>javaScriptEjemplo</title>
     <script>
         let num=0;
function activar(){

    if(num<=0){
  document.body.innerHTML += "<div><button id='b1'>Nuevo Botón</button></div>";
  num=1;
  }
else{
    reload();
    }
}
      </script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="activar()" value="menu">Activar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para que la pagina se recargue utiliza:

```
location.reload();
```

Puedes leer sobre este método en la [página de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Location/reload).